# how to draw 100 numbers following exponential distribution (erlang) in python by having k and CV and mean exponential distribution?

Tags: python, exponential-distribution

- how to draw erlang distribution (two parameters k and cv? (k=1,5,10, cv=100%-45%-32%) ) in python by having k and CV and mean exponential distribution=1?

I know numpy.random.exponential(scale=1.0, size=None)¶ by this only has scale but I need two parameters k and cv? (k=1,5,10, cv=100%-45%-32%, )

Answer (score 3):

Guessing, but: the [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) is a special case of the Gamma (with integer shape parameter).

[numpy.random.gamma](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated) takes a shape ($k$) and a scale ($\theta$) parameter. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), for the Gamma distribution mean=$k \theta$, var=$k \theta^2$, so CV=$\sqrt{\textrm{Var}}/m = 1/\sqrt{k}$.  So the **bad news** is that you can't specify $k$ and CV as independent parameters: once you know $k=1,5,10$, you already know that the CV is (as you specify) 1, $1/\sqrt{5}=0.45$, $1/\sqrt{10}=0.32$. The **good news** is that you can pick the scale ($\theta$) parameter any way you want: e.g. you could set $\theta=1$ throughout (in which case the mean will equal $1/\textrm{CV}^2$), or you can specify the mean $m$ and set $\theta=m/k=m \cdot \textrm{CV}^2$.

So e.g. `numpy.random.gamma(shape=5,size=100)` would work (this uses the default scale=1).

If you **really** want to use `numpy.random.exponential` to generate 100 k-Erlang deviates, in a marginally less efficient and transparent way, you can generate a 100*k array and sum up the rows, e.g. for $k=5$/CV=0.45:

```
import numpy.random as npr 
k = 5
npr.exponential(scale=1,size=(100,k)).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Very similar to @Glen_b's but leaving it anyway since it uses different words so might not be *completely* redundant.

Comment: Actually, Ben, I think yours is better. Feel free to edit yours to incorporate anything that was in mine if you think there was anything worth adding (though I don't think there's a need, it looks fine to me).

Comment: @BenBolker thanks the only data I saw in the paper is that mean exponential distribution=1? How to add this? Would you please check this link to see what is the input? https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1051/64cc0c88c92a710e1d3b21251041747dae62.pdf

Comment: don't have time to read in detail. Best guess: they are looking at the flow through k serially linked compartments, each of which have an exponential residence time.  The total residence time from start to finish will then be Erlang(k)-distributed ...

Comment: @BenBolker How to add exponential mean to it? For instance made with exponential mean=1, k=1, and 100 points